# getting passwords to autofill in Android WebView in react-native application

Tags: android, react-native

When using our website on Android in Chrome, I can use a saved password. We have a react native app that uses that website for logins. How can I get that same webpage in a WebView in the react native app to also suggest the username and password?

Inside the app, it prompts me to "save it to Google", but when I log in next time, there are no suggestions. The save worked, as I see it in my Google profile and it is used if I go to the website through Chrome. How can I get the passwords to be suggested inside this login form in the react native application?

Comment: did you fix it ?

Comment: no I did not fix it.